# Difference between previoussibling and previouselementsibling-javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, compare, element, siblings

I wonder if I know What is the difference between javascript `previousSibling` and `previousElementSibling`. I tried and I didn't find any question or article that compare or describe this. Maybe this is for my little javascript knowledge, but I appreciate if explain it.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `previousElementSibling` property returns the previous element of the specified element, in the same tree level.

The difference between this property and `previousSibling`, is that `previousSibling` returns the previous sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while `previousElementSibling` returns the previous sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

```js
//Get the second li element
var liElement = document.getElementById( "target" ) ;

//Get the previous element (→ Text node (line feed and tab character))
var previousSibling = liElement.previousSibling ;
console.log("previousElementSibling::"+previousSibling.data);
console.log("previousSibling.previousElementSibling::",previousSibling.previousElementSibling);

//Get the previous element (→ <li> Element 3 </ li>)
var previousElementSibling = liElement.previousElementSibling ;
console.log("previousElementSibling::",previousElementSibling);
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Element-1</li>↓
 <li id="target">Element-2</li>
 <li>Element-3</li>
</ul>
```